# Bash script to open a port when traffice is being recieved

Tags: bash, shell-script, iptables, netcat

I have 2 Ubuntu boxes one of them acting as an Attack platform (we will call it AP), the other as an already compromised server (we will call it S1).

I have this rule

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -s <IP of AP> --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1234
```

running on the compromised server, it is taking all traffic from my AP that is destined for port 22 and redirecting it to port 1234 at local host. This accomplishes what I was trying to do, except to be able to connect I have to go open a `netcat` listner on S1 to receive the connection.

I would like to write a script that would run in the background and open the `netcat` listner when traffic is being sent to port 1234 on S1. Is this even possible? If so, how?

This is purely for educational purpose just kinda toying around.

Answer (score 1):

TCP traffic doesn't work like that. You need the listener running before you have a connection, so that the client can connect to it

Comment: What about a systemd socket?

Comment: @AdminBee the socket still needs to be listened on by a listener - it's just that in the systemd case the listener is systemd.